# OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected (UDP Client Program)

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to learn how to code a program for UDP clients from the "Black Hat Python" book, and it's outputting an error: OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected. I'm using a Mac btw.

```
import socket

target_host = "127.0.0.1"   
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

client.sendto("AAABBBCCC".encode(), (target_host, target_port))

data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)

client.close()

print(data)
```

Comment: For UDP it should be SOCK_DGRAM and not SOCK_STREAM.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much, my bad